# Angular email custom with regular validation

Tags: angularjs

I need to perform two steps in order to validate email.
First i want to use angular

```
 type="email"
```

in order to check email validity then i want to use custom directive in order to send this email to server to perform some checks there.

**custom validation direcitve code:**

```
angular.module('app.register')
.directive('emailAvailable',['registerResource', function(registerResource) {
return {

    restrict: 'A',

    require: 'ngModel',

    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        function customValidator(ngModelValue) {
            registerResource.emailAvailable.save({"email": ngModelValue},
                function(response){
                    // Show that email is valid
                },
                function(response){
                   // Show that email is not valid
                });
            return ngModelValue;
        }
        ctrl.$parsers.push(customValidator);
    }
};
```

My question how to execute my customValidator function after angular type="email" is checked for validity.

Comment: You should use an asynchronous validator instead of a parser. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators

Comment: How does asyn is working after angular validated email by type? I Want send request to server only if email is valid.

Comment: The doc I linked to says: *Also, all asynchronous validators will only run once all synchronous validators have passed.*

Comment: @JBNizet works perfect

Answer (score 3):

Using a custom validator, you can do something like this:

```
  var app = angular.module('form-example1', []);
  // only allows e-mail from google
  var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){5,}@g(oogle)?mail\.com$/;
  app.directive('email', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$validators.email = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
          if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
            // consider empty models to be valid
            return true;
          }

          if (EMAIL_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
            // it is valid
            return true;
          }

          // it is invalid
          return false;
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

[Working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pvi1h18IpJmfFaoiHSw1?p=preview).